# HPA (Host Protected Area) disabled. Bad consequences?

Tags: ssd, flash, data-integrity, hdparm

If an SSD's HPA is disabled, then are there any bad consequences? (In terms of data integrity, wear leveling, etc.)

Do the following options make any difference to the SSD controller?

1. HPA disabled, 10% OP (Over-Provisioning).
2. HPA set to 10%, no OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSD's need overprovisioning to work well (as you said wear-leveling etc.). There is some overprovisioning built in and depending on the drive, it may be slightly or not-so-slightly useful to overprovision more. I usually do.

Having

1. HPA disabled with 10% OP with the OP area empty/discarded vs.
2. HPA at 10% with the HPA area empty/discarded

should essentially be the same as far as I know. I do not know of a good reason why treating HPA differently would be useful enough to warrant its implementation, but if anyone knows better, please correct me.

It should also be not exactly the same but also not very far from having 10% (extra) free and discarded space on your partitions, if your OS does reliable discarding of unused old space. Small fragments of free space are usually not discarded.

To reiterate, having 10% HPA with the HPA filled with some data should be the same as 10% over-provisioning with the same leftover data on those 10%. Whether the data pattern matters if it is not discarded, depends on whether the drive does compression, deduplication, discards zeroes etc.

Comment: AFAIK, OP = unallocated space != free space.

Comment: User side OP done right is unallocated space. TRIMmed free space is close but not exactly the same as virgin unallocated space.

Comment: If i disable HPA, then my SSD has 0% OP?

Comment: As said, SSD require OP and have some amount of build-in OP regardless of HPA.